# Fighting client-side caching in Django

Tags: django, caching

I'm using the render_to_response shortcut and don't want to craft a specific Response object to add additional headers to prevent client-side caching.

I'd like to have a response that contains:

- Pragma: no-cache
- Cache-control : no-cache
- Cache-control: must-revalidate

And all the other nifty ways that browsers will hopefully interpret as directives to avoid caching.

Is there a no-cache middleware or something similar that can do the trick with minimal code intrusion?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You can achieve this using the cache_control decorator. Example from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/cache/#controlling-cache-using-other-headers):

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

@never_cache
def myview(request):
   # ...
```

Comment: To make this work on all browsers (specifically FireFox and Opera, it worked fine on IE and Safari/Chrome) I needed to manually add `response["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"` along with `@never_cache`.    `@never_cache` calls `add_never_cache_headers()` and this in turn calls `patch_cache_control()` but this only adds `Cache-Control:max-age=0`, which apparently is not enough for these browsers. See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers

Comment: After exploring the django code a bit more I found a cleaner way of adding that header:     
    `patch_cache_control(response, no_cache=True, no_store=True, must_revalidate=True)  `

Comment: Ah, there is already an open ticket for this at code.djangoproject.com: [@never_cache decorator should add 'no-cache' & 'must-revalidate'](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13008)

Comment: @AJJ I think you also missed `response['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'`

Comment: Update in 2018: ```@never_cache``` has been fixed to work on all browsers.

Comment: How do I handled this with class based views?

Comment: My tests showed `@never_cache` seems to disable the server-side cache as well.

Answer (score 56):

This approach (slight modification of L. De Leo's solution) with a custom middleware has worked well for me as a site wide solution:

```
from django.utils.cache import add_never_cache_headers

class DisableClientSideCachingMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        add_never_cache_headers(response)
        return response
```

This makes use of [`add_never_cache_headers`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/utils/#django.utils.cache.add_never_cache_headers).

---

If you want to combine this with `UpdateCacheMiddleware` and `FetchFromCacheMiddleware`, to enable server-side caching while disabling client-side caching, you need to add `DisableClientSideCachingMiddleware` before everything else, like this:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'custom.middleware.DisableClientSideCachingMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    # ... all other middleware ...
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
)
```

Comment: +1 for using `add_never_cache_headers` instead of manually inserting headers.

Comment: I've packaged something based upon this. It is now available on PyPI, and github. https://github.com/incuna/django-never-cache-post

Comment: Just an fyi: This doesn't really work for Opera and page-caching, because add_never_cache just sets max-age to zero, and O, and Opera doesn't seem to honor max-age for that purpose. See http://my.opera.com/yngve/blog/2007/02/27/introducing-cache-contexts-or-why-the

Comment: Not exactly, @AdamC.  Going back at least to Django 1.5, `add_never_cache_headers` also sets  Expires and Last-Modified headers to the current time. It will also set ETag headers to avert caching if USE_ETAGS is set in your settings. See https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/cache.py

Comment: Awesome answer.  I posted a rewrite for django 1.10+ https://stackoverflow.com/a/47684405/2800876

Comment: This works great. Side note: `add_never_cache_headers()` only sets headers if they are not set yet - it doesn't overwrite existing headers.
In my case the 'Expires'  header was already set. To overwrite it this line is sufficient: `response['Expires'] = http_date(time.time())`. It can be added either directly above or below `add_never_cache_headers()`. The additional imports: ```import time
from django.utils.http import http_date```

Answer (score 17):

To supplement existing answers. Here is a decorator that adds additional headers to disable caching:

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import patch_cache_control
from functools import wraps

def never_ever_cache(decorated_function):
    """Like Django @never_cache but sets more valid cache disabling headers.

    @never_cache only sets Cache-Control:max-age=0 which is not
    enough. For example, with max-axe=0 Firefox returns cached results
    of GET calls when it is restarted.
    """
    @wraps(decorated_function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        response = decorated_function(*args, **kwargs)
        patch_cache_control(
            response, no_cache=True, no_store=True, must_revalidate=True,
            max_age=0)
        return response
    return wrapper
```

And you can use it like:

```
class SomeView(View):
    @method_decorator(never_ever_cache)
    def get(self, request):
        return HttpResponse('Hello')
```

Comment: Can someone explain the down vote? I wonder if something is fundamentally wrong with the code, because I depend on it in a production system.

Comment: +1 Works fine for me as well and I do not see any problem either. To hear a reason from the downvoter would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

I was scratching my head when the three magic `meta` didn't work in Firefox and Safari.

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Apparently it can happen because some browsers will ignore the client side `meta`, so it should be handled at server side.

I tried all the answers from this post for my class based views (`django==1.11.6`). But referring to answers from @Lorenzo and @Zags, I decided to write a middleware which I think is a simple one.

So adding to other good answers,

```
# middleware.py
class DisableBrowserCacheMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        response['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
        response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'
        response['Expires'] = '0'
        return response

# settings.py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'myapp.middleware.DisableBrowserCacheMiddleware',
    ...
```

Comment: using django 4.1 and I believe this is still the best way to prevent client-side caching site-wide.

Answer (score 8):

Actually writing my own middleware was easy enough:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


class NoCacheMiddleware(object):

    def process_response(self, request, response):

        response['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
        response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache must-revalidate proxy-revalidate'

        return response
```

Still doesn't really behave like i wanted but so neither does the @never_cache decorator

Comment: This answer to *Making sure a web page is not cached, across all browsers* is quite detailed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers

Answer (score 7):

Regarding the Google Chrome browser (Version 34.0.1847.116 m) and the other browsers, I found that only the `@cache_control` decorator is working. I use Django 1.6.2.

Use it like this:

```
@cache_control(max_age=0, no_cache=True, no_store=True, must_revalidate=True)
def view(request):
    ...
```

Comment: What's the best way to do this when one's using class-based views?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a rewrite of [@Meilo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5882033/2800876) for Django 1.10+:

```
from django.utils.cache import add_never_cache_headers

class DisableClientCachingMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        add_never_cache_headers(response)
        return response
```

Answer (score 0):

For Django 4+:

```
from django.utils.cache import add_never_cache_headers


def disable_client_side_caching_middleware(get_response):
    def middleware(request):
        response = get_response(request)
        add_never_cache_headers(response)
        return response

    return middleware
```

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'my_app.middleware.disable_client_side_caching_middleware'
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with newer version of Django 4.0+

```
class DisableClientSideCachingMiddleware:
    """
    Middleware to disable client side caching, that is on browser.
    Adds a Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private header ,
    to a response to indicate that a page should never be cached.

    If not added and the api returns a cached response, the browser also caches the data into disk cache.
    Meaning we don't want caching to happen at browser level on client side as clinent will see data from
    disk cache even if it is changed on server side.

    """

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        add_never_cache_headers(response)
        return response
```

Then add this middleware in your settings,

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'your_app.middleware.DisableClientSideCachingMiddleware'
    ...
)
```