# To disable css cache of Chrome in iPhone, using django runserver

Tags: iphone, django, html, google-chrome

I'm developing a html5 mobile site, with django as the backend and test server, testing the page in Chrome and Safari in my iPhone.

The problems is, when I changed my css or js files, refreshing Safari will reload the new static files, but Chrome will not, not matter how many times I do refresh.

How can I disable Chrome cache of static files? Chrome setting? Or change my django app code to add some http headers?

Comment: Maybe the discussion here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095520/fighting-client-side-caching-in-django) will help you, the "@never_cache" decorator could make the job!

Comment: @Ricola3D The css/js are served as `static` files by django's default mechanism, not by my views. I'm new to django, not really know how do apply this decorator, if possible.